# disable or detect Default Configuration

Tags: php, log4php

I have php file which contains class "FooClass" uses in a few projects. I recently add method for logging with log4net like this:

```
private static function log($message,$level=0)
{
    if(!isset(self::$logger))
    {
        if(!class_exists("Logger")) return;
        self::$logger = Logger::getLogger("DBw");
        if(!isset(self::$logger)) return;
    }
    //logging
}
```

Some files that use FooClass can define the configuration by ising Logger::configure("config.xml").
But others don't define it, and in that case the FooClass start to use LoggerConfiguratorDefault, which trace logs as "echo". This is not acceptable.

I want to see if the configuration is not defined by other files, the FooClass did not log with LoggerConfiguratorDefault.

How can I do disable LoggerConfiguratorDefault or detect using of that and make return from function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was in the same position, slightly different case: My configuration object does log if I access a value, but it cannot log if I access the config value for the configuration file of the logger.

The class `Logger`of log4php has a private static property `$initialized`, which is accessed through a private static method `isInitialized()`. I solved my problem by using Reflection to access the value of the static property, and if the result was `false` I returned a self-created `NullLogger extends Logger` that does nothing if any logging methods are called.

Your class might be able to do the same, but the better solution will be to ensure log4php always is initialized.

I'd suggest that you create a ticket in the projects Jira to have this issue resolved more easily. There really is no need to have the `Logger::isInitialized()` method private.

Comment: I don't know what is projects Jira. Can you reference me? Can you give me code example of your solution.

Comment: I'm referencing this page here: http://logging.apache.org/log4php/issue-tracking.html

Comment: Ok, I took the liberty of creating an issue ticket and patch: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4PHP-197